# AWS CloudWatch filter for multiple log strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am creating a line chart in a CloudWatch dashboard. I can create a line representing the frequency with which one string appears the logs, using a filter. But, I don't know how to create two or more such lines.

After selecting a log group, I run this query:

```
filter name = "first log string"
| stats count(*) as firstString by bin(1hour)
```

This generates counts of results that, in the Visiulization tab, are displayed as a line chart with a single line.

Now I want to add another line representing "second log string" on the chart. I assume I will have to modify the filter in some way, or add a second filter.

Here are some things that don't work:

- adding a second name to the filter
- trying `filter @message` or `@name` as [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-examples.html) suggests
- simply pasting in a modified duplicate of the query

Further, I seem to lack documentation that explains how `filter` is supposed to work. Search engines keep sending me back to this [Filter And Pattern Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) AWS document which dosen't appear to give any actual examples using `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I had to use an array in my filter. I also used the `sum()` function instead of `count()`.

```
filter name in ["first log string", "second log string"]
| fields name = "first log string" as first_string, name = "second log string" as second_string
| stats sum(first_string) as first_string, sum(second_string) as second_string by bin(1hour)
```

Now I have a line chart with two lines representing the frequency of two logged items